# Reflection with Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, datagridview

In my DataGridView, I am assigning my values to cells like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());

    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["pointidentifier"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].pointidentifier;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["pointname"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].pointname;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["backup"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].backup;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["covenable"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].covenable;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["covlifetime"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].covlifetime;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["covtarget"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].covtarget;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["description"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].description;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["historyenable"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].historyenable;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["pointaddress"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].pointaddress;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["pointtype"].Value = pointCommonInfo[i].pointtype;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["activetext"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].activetext;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["alarmenable"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].alarmenable;

    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[i].Cells["alarmenablehigh"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].alarmenablehigh;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[i].Cells["alarmenablelow"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].alarmenablelow;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["alarmvalue"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].alarmvalue;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["correctvalue"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].correctvalue;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells["covincrement"].Value = pointSpecificInfo[i].covincrement;
    ...
```

Pretty dirty stuff. The cell names match the properties of my List of pointCommonInfo and pointSpecificInfo, so I decided to do use reflection:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    int j = i + 1;
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows.Add(new DataGridViewRow());
    FieldInfo[] fieldCommon = typeof(PointCommonInformation).GetFields();
    FieldInfo[] fieldSpecific = typeof(PointSpecificInformation).GetFields();
    foreach (FieldInfo field in fieldCommon)
    {
        DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells[field.Name].Value = //?
    }

    foreach (FieldInfo field in fieldSpecific)
    {
        DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells[field.Name].Value = //?
    }   
}
```

I can get the names of the field, but I don't know how to actually access them using reflection. Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you say - cell names match to the properties of pointCommonInfo and pointSpecificInfo - then you should use GetProperties() instead of GetFields(). You can achieve it as following:

```
Type commonType = typeof(PointCommonInformation);

foreach (PropertyInfo item in commonType.GetProperties())
{
        object propertyObject = item.GetValue(pointCommonInfo, null);
        string propertyValue = propertyObject == null ? string.Empty : propertyObject.ToString();
        DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells[item.Name].Value = propertyValue;    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `FieldInfo.GetValue` Method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.fieldinfo.getvalue.aspx.

```
foreach (FieldInfo field in fieldCommon)
{
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells[field.Name].Value = field.GetValue(pointCommonInfo[i]);
}

foreach (FieldInfo field in fieldSpecific)
{
    DGVPointCtrl.Rows[j].Cells[field.Name].Value = field.GetValue(pointCommonInfo[i]);
}
```